# Primes $p=1\pmod 5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, field-theory, normed-spaces, cyclotomic-fields

Let $p=1\pmod 5$ be a prime. Then

$p=x^4 + x^3z + x^2z^2 + 5xy^3 - 5xy^2z + xz^3 + 5y^4 - 10y^3z + 10y^2z^2 - 5yz^3 + z^4$

for integers $x, y,$ and $z$.

Is there a proof for this?

For instance the fifth cyclotomic field $\mathbb Q (e^{i\frac{\pi}{5}})$ is of degree $4$ and class number one, so each prime $p=1\pmod 5$ is written as the norm of an element

$aw^3+bw^2+cw+d$

```
(13:58) gp > norm(Mod(a*x^3+b*x^2+c*x+d,polcyclo(5)))
%41 = a^4 + (-b + (-c - d))*a^3 + (b^2 + (2*c + 2*d)*b + (c^2 - 3*d*c + d^2))*a^2 + (-b^3 + (-3*c + 2*d)*b^2 + (2*c^2 - d*c - 3*d^2)*b + (-c^3 + 2*d*c^2 + 2*d^2*c - d^3))*a + (b^4 + (-c - d)*b^3 + (c^2 + 2*d*c + d^2)*b^2 + (-c^3 - 3*d*c^2 + 2*d^2*c - d^3)*b + (c^4 - d*c^3 + d^2*c^2 - d^3*c + d^4))
```

where

$w=e^{i\frac{\pi}{5}}$, a fifth root of unity. However, the element contains four parameters, whereas the form of interest contains three? Is it still suitable to represent all primes $p$ congruent to $1\pmod 5$?

Comment: well, I got all those primes up to 1000, but still,with $|x|,|y|,|z| \leq 100 $ do not have primes 1181, 1931, 2111 for example. That is with your $p=x^4 + \cdots$ item.

Comment: No proof yet, but it appears that the $x^4 + \cdots$ has a lower bound that depends on $|x+y|.$ If so, the computations are effective and the answer to your question is no. I will try allowing the variable $z$ to have larger absolute value, see if anything changes.

Comment: more realistic to look for the minimum on, for example, $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1.$ If that minimum is a strictly positive constant,...

Comment: @WillJagy It appears $1181$ is the first counterexample, as you pointed out earlier. What is confusing though is the smaller primes have solution but some larger primes don't. If the answer to the question is no, then I estimate that at some point as $p$ increases, more primes will not have a solution.

Comment: The possible importance of inequalities: The quadratic form $x^2 + 2 y^2 + 3 z^2$ integrally represents $2$ and all odd numbers. If we switch to $x^4 + 2 y^4 + 3 z^4,$ the volume of the solid $x^4 + 2 y^4 + 3 z^4 \leq M$ for large positive $M$ is proportional to $M^{3/4}.$ The number of standard lattice points is similar to this volume, as a result, the quartic cannot represent all primes or even a positive proportion of primes. It might represent infinitely many primes, in which case there would be an annoying alternation of hits/misses

Answer (score 2):

Take $w$ being a fifth root of unity and $K = \mathbb{Q}(w)$.  The ring of algebraic integers is $O := \mathbb{Z}[w]$ and ideal-class group is trivial (you can compute this for instance with Sage or Magma). That means that every ideal is in $O$ is principal.

If $p$ is 1 mod 5, then $\mathbb{F}_p$ contains a 5'th root of unity, and hence $x^5-1$ splits over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Then the minimal polynomial of $w$, which is $(x^5-1)/(x-1)$, also splits over $\mathbb{F}_p$. That implies that the ideal $(p) \subset O$ splits, it factors as a product of 4 ideals, each of which has Norm $p$.  Now take one of those 4 ideals. Since the class group is trivial, it follows that that ideal is principal, say, equal to $(g)$.

The Norm of $g$ is $\pm$ the Norm of the ideal $(g)$, so it is $\pm p$, but we can easily rule out $-p$ because no element of $K$ has negative Norm. So the Norm of $g$ is $p$.

Now the Norm of $h := x + (y-z) w - y w^2$ is precisely the polynomial you gave.   Notice that the $w^3$ term does not appear.

So the question then becomes: Given $g$, does there exist a unit $u \in O$ such that $ug$ is $w^3$-less? The group of units is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/10 \oplus \mathbb{Z}$.  I suspect that in general the answer is no, and that this can be settled with a finite computation. Say the units are generated by $-1,w,u$. So now we have to check if there exist $k,n$ for which $\pm w^k u^n$ is $w^3$-less. The $\pm$ does not matter. Fix $k \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and denote the $w^3$-coefficient of $w^k u^n g$ as $a_n$.  Then $a_n$ satisfies a linear recurrence relation, with constant coefficients, of order 4. The characteristic polynomial of this recurrence relation is the minpoly of $u$.

We have to show that $a_n \neq 0$ for any integer $n$.  One plan would be to find some prime number $q$ for which $a_n \not\equiv 0$ mod $q$ for all $n$ (the latter is a finite computation because the sequence $(a_n)$ repeats mod $q$.

Remains to do:  find suitable $p$ (some were mentioned in a comment). Then compute $a_n$ and find suitable $q$ (for each $k=0,\ldots,4$).

Added later:  Now that I actually did the computation, I find that it is not necessary to look for such $q$.  The group of units is generated by: $-1$ (order 2), $w$ (order 5), and $u$ = golden ratio $= -(w^2+w^3)$ (infinity order). This means that the recurrence relation is: $a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + a_0$ but for those sequences it is very easy to verify if $0$ is a member of the sequence or not because for $n>>0$ the sequence grows as constant times $u^n$ while for $n<<0$ it grows as constant times $(-u)^n$.

So the computation is now as follows: $p = 1181$ and $g := w^3+3w^2-4w-2$ has Norm $p$. So the factorization of the ideal $(p)$ is $(g) (g_2) (g_3) (g_4)$ where $g_i$ is obtained from $g$ by replacing $w$ with $w^i$  (i.e. the $g_i$ are obtained from $g$ by applying elements of the Galois group).

Next, take $k=0$ and let $a_n$ be the $w^3$-coefficient of $w^k u^n g$. You only have to compute that for $n=0$ and $n=1$ because then all other $a_n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ are determined by the recurrence relation. One finds $a_0, a_1 = 1,-4$. Then the recurrence tells us: $\ldots,a_{-4},\ldots,a_4,\ldots = \ldots,17, -11, 6, -5, 1, -4, -3, -7, -10,\ldots$ and it is clear from $a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + a_0$ that this sequence does not contain $0$.

Repeat this for $k=1,2,3,4$.  In principle we have to repeat this for $g_2$, $g_3$, and $g_4$ but this can be avoided with a short argument. In any case, this  reduces the problem to a finite computation.